# Prove that a linear transformation exists with certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Let $V$ be a finite vector space and $U$ a sub-vector space to $V$
>
> Prove that a linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$ exists, where:
>
> $\ker T = U$ & $\ker T \cap\operatorname{Im}T = \{0\}$

I understand that each vector in $U$ is a vector that follows:
$v \in V$ & $T(v)=0$

And technically $U$ can just be the zero vector space, and $T(v) =v$

But this doesn't feel like a proof to me, if anybody can help me understand better how to approach such a question, that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $W$ be an arbitrary complement of $U$ (say, extend a basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$ and keep only the new basis elements).
Then you can apply the identity on $W$.

Comment: I see, so if I assume such a vector space exists, then $V=U\oplus W$ then each of $U$'s basis vectors make $T(u_k) = 0$, but what does it mean about $W$'s vectors?

Comment: Define $u+w\mapsto w$ for $u\in U,\ w\in W$.

Comment: Ah, you're definitely right. In that case, each $T(v)$ is equal to $T(u+w)$, but since $U$ is the kernel, we can say that $T(v)=T(w)$.
So therefore, $W$ is the image of the linear transformation $T$?